# How to find similar elements in selenium?

Tags: python-3.x, selenium-webdriver, find, element

I am trying to make a selection on a page (to pick a button with a specific time in it as a label) where there are up to 40 possibilities. I had been constructing the xpath i needed dynamically, but have found that changes may occur to the xpath that i cannot predict and program for (other special messages may appear that change the div[XX] parameter earlier in the xpath). I have tried various searches using the text i am looking for (here is one variation - i have tried 10+:

br.find_element_by_xpath('//*[contains(text(), "4:30")]')

I was hoping someone more experienced than me might have an idea of how to construct a search that will uniquely return what i am looking for. Here is the html for two successive elements:

First element (for the 2:40 button):
[image]

Second element (for the 2:50 button):
[image]

The only difference i can see is the time and i can't figure out how to use selenium to conduct a successful find_element_by...Thanks for any answers/advice you may have.

Comment: You can search for custom labels using a css selector that would look something like this [data-ftjson ~="2:50"]

Anyway it is poor code practice to have lots of elements that cannot be uniquely identified and you should instead make sure that these elements are all given an unique ID or label that you can use instead

Comment: Thanks I will follow the direction you have provided. The site is a third party site, i have no influence over how it is constructed. I am using selenium to automate my use of the site...Stay well.